# Overflow for slick slider with fixed background, how to prevent image cropping on slide?

Tags: html, css, layout, z-index, slick.js

There is a stylized slick-slider where the image should go beyond the top border:
[image]
At the same time, for .slick-list I have a background set (which is fixed, only the content is scrolled - text, picture and button):
[image]
How can I prevent the picture from being cropped?

Comment: how does your image coming is it a background image or coming from HTML  `img` tag?  if it is a background image then you can try  `background-size :cover`.

Comment: are you talking about cropping or CUTTING at the top?
if CUTTING

`.home-slider .slick-list { overflow: visible; overflow-x: clip; }`

Comment: @Alex, im talking about cutting at the top. Did as you said, it gets cutting anyway:
https://i.ibb.co/B676Dhm/2021-12-17-22-40-41.png

Moreover, if we remove the property overflow, the image stops cutting, but clones of the slider become visible:
https://i.ibb.co/Kh9Bnk7/2021-12-17-22-45-28.png

Comment: Timur, can you create jsfiddle or codepen with this issue and share a link?

Comment: @Alex, here: http://dev.web-tim.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are steps how to fix it

1. add to css

`.home-slider .slick-list { overflow: visible !important; }` - you need IMPORTANT as `{overflow: hidden}` will be added to the element style during the animation.
Clones on left/right should be visible

2. add new CSS selector + styles

```
.home-slider.slick-slider {
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Clones shouldn't be visible. But you have wrong position for the button and dots at the bottom

3. wrap(create parent `div.home-slider-wrapper`) the `div.home-slider` in the `div.home-slider-wrapper` at your html
4. add to css

```
.home-slider-wrapper {position: relative;}
```

5. align button + dots, position of these elements calculated from `.home-slider-wrapper`

Comment: Alex, thank you very much!
I did everything as you wrote. 
The box-shadow started cropping a little, I corrected it.

Comment: You are welcome, человек человеку друг ;)